# awk command to extract particular string based on multiple pattern string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have following string in a file called **ddl.txt**

```
CREATE SET TABLE DB.TABLE1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL (
      key DECIMAL(18,0);

drop table DB.dummy;
create table DB.dummy (id varchar(10));
```

I need to extract table names in above file as follows which contain key words 'TABLE' & 'CREATE' but in different pattern, (**Expected Output**)

```
TABLE1
dummy
```

what i tried is,

```
a=`cat ddl.txt`
a=`echo "$a" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]`

echo "$a" | awk -v RS=, '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/{print $NF}' | awk -F'.' '{print $2}'
```

**This is returning only**

```
TABLE1
```

I need the other table name `dummy` which is in different pattern search.

Note: Always we should check the pattern is matching with keywords TABLE & CREATE as i used in above query; also DB is dynamic ... it is not always DB

Answer (score 1):

Will this help?

```
$ cat t.awk
/CREATE.*TABLE/{table1=$5}
/create table/{table2=$4}
END{
    print table1
    print table2
}

$ awk -F'[ .]' -f t.awk input.txt
TABLE1
dummy
```

**Update**

Assume the folllowing input:

```
CREATE SET TABLE DB.TABLE1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL (
      key DECIMAL(18,0);

drop table DB.dummy;
create table DB.dummy (id varchar(10));

CREATE SET TABLE BD.TABLE2 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL (
      key DECIMAL(18,0);

drop table BD.dummier;
create table BD.dummier (id varchar(10));
```

awk:

```
/CREATE.*TABLE/{
    t1[n++] = $5
}
/create table/{
    t2[k++] = $4
}
END{
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        print t1[i], t2[i]
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -F'[ .]' -f t.awk input.txt
TABLE1 dummy
TABLE2 dummier
```

Comment: I may have n number of tables which is not fixed. can you give me a dynamic solution ?

Comment: yes if you update your question so that I understand what you need :-)

Comment: I updated question.. also DB is dynamic ... it is not always DB

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you meant, I would do this :

```
$ cat a
CREATE SET TABLE DB.TABLE1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL (
      key DECIMAL(18,0);

drop table DB.dummy;
create table DB.dummy (id varchar(10));

$ kw="DB." # you can set kw according to what happens previously
$ awk -F"$kw" '(($0~/table/ || $0~/TABLE/) && ($0~/create/ || $0~/CREATE/)){print $2}' a | awk '{print $1}'

 TABLE1
 dummy
```

I assume the name are always after "DB." pattern

Comment: but in may case `db` should be used as key word as it may vary. we can use `.` but need to take if somewhere dot is coming ... `please reframe the command accordingly`

Comment: If you know the keyword, you can pass it to awk instead of "DB."

Comment: sorry what i meant is db should not be used as key

Comment: why not? After the edit you can easily modify DB with the keyword you want.

Comment: DB is dynamic word; only CREATE and TABLE are static

Comment: Could it be that in one file, there are DB.TABLE and foo.dummy for instance ? Or in the same file there would always be the same keyword whatever it is ?
And, are the name of the table always at the same position ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way with `GNU awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}
/create/&&/table/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/[.]/){split($i,tmp,/\./); print tmp[2]}}' ddl.txt
```

**Output:**

```
TABLE1
dummy
```

Comment: but in may case `db` should be used as key word as it may vary. we can use `.` but need to take if somewhere dot is coming ... `please reframe the command accordingly`